# How memory-efficient is Binary Tree implementation in Java?

Tags: java, memory, binary-tree, insertion

So I just wrote code for insertion of nodes in binary tree (NOT BST).

I noticed that every time the recursive insert returns a 'node', it is assigned to the initial node.

Does this mean, that the memory reference of root of this tree would change on the completion of each insert?

```
public  void add(int data)
{
    root=add(root,data);
}

public static BinaryNode add(BinaryNode node, int data) {


    if(node==null)
    {
        node=new BinaryNode(data);

    }
    else {
        ///IF not 1st element, flow enters this part
        if(node.left==null && node.right==null)
        {
            node.left=add(node.right,data);
        }
        else if (node.right == null) {
            node.right=add(node.right, data);

        } else {
            node.left=add(node.left, data);

        } 
    }
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `add` the only time you change `node` is if the tree at that point is empty, so the answer is no except for the first insert.

However, note that you add a new level to the tree only on the left (first `if` condition) so the "tree" you build is highly unbalanced to the left.  This isn't really a "tree", it's more like a strange linked list.  Also, since you don't maintain any particular sequence it can't be better than a simple unordered list for searches.